# Parsing a .csv file from a server with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5, csv

I have looked for an answer of a long time and still not found one so I thought I'd ask the question myself.

In my iPad app, I need to have the capability of parsing a .csv file in order to populate a table. I am using http://michael.stapelberg.de/cCSVParse to parse the csv files. However, I have only been successful in parsing local files.  I have been trying to access a file from a server but am getting nowhere.

Here is my code to parse a local .csv file:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        //UITextField *reply = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        NSString *fileName = input.text;
        NSLog(@"fileName %@", fileName);
        CSVParser *parser = [CSVParser new];
        if ([fileName length] != 0)
        {
            NSString *pathAsString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"csv"];
            NSLog(@"%@", pathAsString);

            if (pathAsString != nil)
            {
                [parser openFile:pathAsString];
                NSMutableArray *csvContent = [parser parseFile];
                NSLog(@"%@", csvContent);
                [parser closeFile];
                NSMutableArray *heading = [csvContent objectAtIndex:0];
                [csvContent removeObjectAtIndex:0];

                NSLog(@"%@", heading);

                AppDelegate *ap = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
                NSManagedObjectContext *context = [ap managedObjectContext];

                NSString *currentHeader = [heading objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *currentValueInfo = [heading objectAtIndex:1];
                NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Field" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                [newObject setValue:@"MIS" forKey:@"header"];
                [newObject setValue:currentHeader forKey:@"fieldName"];

                for (NSArray *current in csvContent)
                {
                    NSManagedObject *newField = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Field" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    [newField setValue:currentHeader forKey:@"header"];
                    [newField setValue:currentValueInfo forKey:@"valueInfo"];
                    NSLog(@"%@", [current objectAtIndex:0]);
                    [newField setValue:[current objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"fieldName"];
                    [newField setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[current objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]] forKey:@"value"];
                }
                NSError *error;
                if (![context save:&error]) 
                {
                    NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                [self storeArray];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }
    }
    input.text = nil;
}
```

Forgive the weird beginning and ending brace indentation. :/

Anyway, so that is my code to take input from a user and access a file locally which I'm sure you guys have realized already.  Now I want to know how to get the path of a file in my server.

Also if you guys see anything else wrong such as writing style and other bad habits please tell me as I'm new to iOS.

Thank you so much in advance! If you didn't understand my question please clarify as I'm bad at explaining myself at times! :)

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you have a server ? do you put your csv file in the server ? Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: It seems to me that there are several steps involved here - 1. How to get a file from a server 2. How to keep that file locally (memory or disk) 3. how to get the file into the parser. 4. display it. Which of these steps are causing you trouble? It seems you have the last two under control, am I right?

Comment: @Monolo you are absolutely right. There are several steps involved. And yes I have the last 2 under control. The problem I am having is obtaining the path to the file. I guess I can store the file locally after which getting the path name should not be an issue.

Comment: @samirFrance yes i have a server and the .csv file is in the server. My problem is that I don't know how to obtain the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am guessing you are trying to get data from a server's .csv file and want to show that data in table view list.

so I suggest you try to get that .csv file data in NSData and then work on that.

```
NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"serverUrl"]];
NSString *csvResponseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"responseString--->%@",csvResponseString);
```

Now try to use nsstring's method (`componentsSeparatedByString`) with coma (')

```
arrSepratedData = [[responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now use this arr for `UITableView` data populate.

Comment: Hi! I had already tried your method and it works. But my problem is that I need a file path. Only then will the parser be able to use it. I need to keep it uniform through my app. So due to build issues i cannot use your method. :(

Comment: could you please let me know the flow of ur application..May be it helps me and others . And also explain is there necessary to save data in local database/Coredata.if possible send the .csv file data it will help to understand ..